# Can't Start/Stop windows service from my web app remotely

Tags: c#, .net, service, wmi

I'm trying to Start/Stop/Restart a windows service from my web applicaton. The below code is the Start function. This code works in the local machine if the usename & password is provided ie, by uncommenting the lines:

```
connectoptions.Username = DomainUsername;
connectoptions.Password = Password;
```

If I run this in other remote server it doesn't works. It's not Starting/Stoping service.

```
#region StartService
public int StartService(string ServiceName, string IPAddress)
{
    int serviceflag = 0;
    try
    {
        //Assign the user name and password of the account to ConnectionOptions object
        //which have administrative privilege on the remote machine.
        ConnectionOptions connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
        connectoptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        //connectoptions.Username = DomainUsername;
        //connectoptions.Password = Password;

        //IP Address of the remote machine

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + IPAddress + @"\root\cimv2", connectoptions);
        //ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();
        scope.Connect();

        //Define the WMI query to be executed on the remote machine
        SelectQuery query0 = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Service  where name = '" + ServiceName + "'");

        object[] methodArgs = { ServiceName,  null, null, 0 };
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query0))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
            {
                if (service.GetPropertyValue("State").ToString().ToLower().Equals("running"))
                {
                    serviceflag = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    service.InvokeMethod("StartService", methodArgs);
                }
            }
        }

        return serviceflag;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        serviceflag = 2;
        return serviceflag;
    }
}
#endregion
```

There are other functions like ***IsServiceInstalled*** (shows service is installed on not in the app) and ***IsServiceRunning*** (shows service is running or not). Both these functions are working fine.

```
#region IsServiceRunning
public bool IsServiceRunning(string ServiceName0, string IPAddress)
{
    try
    {
        int serviceexistsflag1 = 0;
        //Assign the user name and password of the account to ConnectionOptions object
        //which have administrative privilege on the remote machine.
        ConnectionOptions connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
        connectoptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        //connectoptions.Username = DomainUsername;
        //connectoptions.Password = Password;

        //IP Address of the remote machine

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + IPAddress + @"\root\cimv2", connectoptions);
        //ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();
        scope.Connect();
        //Define the WMI query to be executed on the remote machine
        SelectQuery query0 = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Service  where name = '" + ServiceName0 + "'");

        object[] methodArgs = { ServiceName0, null, null, 0 };
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query0))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
            {
                if (service.GetPropertyValue("State").ToString().ToLower().Equals("running"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //service.InvokeMethod("StartService", methodArgs);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
#endregion
```

So what will be the problem with Start function?

Comment: So the obvious response is... which profile is this Service running under? It works locally but not on server, does the "Local System" or "Network Service" have access? To trouble shoot it can you write to a log file to identify the line it fails on so we can narrow the problem domain?

Comment: Also which account is the web app running under in IIS? Have you tried to start the service with its credentials, "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool"

Comment: Just making sure you've read on https://www.bing.com/search?q=ntlm+onehop - most likely you are as you are working with remote administration...

Comment: Sorry. As I'm new & fresher to this it will take time for me to reply the above questions. I'll try to clarify my problem once again. 

If I run the app in my local system and Stop the service (in the remote server) using the app, it stops.
But when I run the app in that remote server (where the service is running) It says "User credentials cannot be used for local connections"

So I commented the username and password part in the code

Now it don't shows the error. But when I stop the service from my app, its not actually stopping the sevice.